# Using y'' in numerical iteration

Tags: numerical-methods

Lets say I know $y(x_1), y'(x_1), y''(x_1), y(x_2), y'(x_2), y''(x_2)$ values exactly

I know only 2 points. What is the best way to find $y(x_3)$?

I don't know how I would include the second derivative into the midpoint rule. I also don't want to only use $y(x_2)$

Comment: This calls for [Hermite interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_interpolation).

Comment: exactly, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You could use a Taylor Series Expansion about the point closest to $x_3$... say WLOG $x_2$:

$$y(x_3)\approx y(x_2)+(x_3-x_2)\cdot y'(x_2)+\frac{(x_3-x_2)^2}{2}\cdot y''(x_2).$$

My understanding is that there are ways of employing the data at $x_1$ also in such a framework --- perhaps somebody else might enlighten both of us.

- Particularly if the $y''(x_2)\neq y''(x_3)$ then perhaps you could fit a cubic to the data you have at $x_2$ and $x_3$. I think in theory you could fit a degree five as you have six equations --- although sometimes the higher degree the polynomial fit, the more wibbly it gets... at least you would have a unique solution unlike degrees three and four.
- You could also build up a finite difference table using the derivatives you have.

I think I like the degree five polynomial fit to be honest.

Write 
$$f(x)=ax^5+bx^4+cx^3+dx^2+ex+f.$$

Find the first two derivatives in terms of the parameters $a...f$.

Now input $x_1$ and $x_2$ into the six functions to generate six equations in six unknowns. Solve the resulting linear system and you have

$$y(x_3)\approx f(x_3).$$

Comment: $$y(x_3)\approx y(x_2)+(x_3-x_2)\cdot y'(x_2)+\frac{(x_3-x_2)^2}{2}\cdot y''(x_2).$$

this is not going to be any better than midpoint rule

Comment: Why not? Is $x_3$ between $x_1$ and $x_2$? If yes this Taylor Expansion will be better than a midpoint rule if $y(x)$ is as simple as a parabola...

Comment: It is going to be only slightly better. For a parabola, midpoint rule is about half as good, but then again, mid point rule is far easier to compute, so it would be able to do it with a much smaller step size in the same time.

Comment: If you want something as easy as the midpoint rule why don't you go and use it? Are you going to get easier?